# Angular factory prototype dissociation on ng-click

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a factory that has a series of prototypes that need to be able to call each other. The problem is the reference to "this" is being applied to the html template rather than the original factory class when using `ng-click`.

Here is an example:

```
angular.factory('myFactory', function(){
    function FactoryA(){}
    FactoryA.prototype.hello = function(){ console.log('Hello') };
    FactoryA.prototype.useHello = function(){ this.hello() };

    return FactoryA;
}
```

The controller will set the factory to $scope variable "myFactory".

The `ng-click` would be called like this from the html template:

```
<button type="button" ng-click="myFactory.useHello()">Hello</button>
```

The problem is that "this" in the context of myFactory.useHello is replaced by the html template reference and loses its link to FactoryA and its other prototypes.

How can I keep ng-click functions associated with the factory class and its other prototypes?

Comment: It is generally accepted as bad practice to expose services/factories of your scope. Precisely for this reason, any changes made through data binding will not only propagate back to the service in your controller but to all uses of it in your application (that is with a service not factory as its a single instance). You should create a click handler in your controller that talks to the service. You could also possibly bind the context of the factory function.

Comment: Can you add the code where you create myFactory in the scope?  I think you're missing to `new` it up.

Comment: Just to explain a bit, I understand the issue with data binding the factory to the controller when using angular for it's intended use building dynamic websites and apps. For my purposes I need the factory to be completely dynamic in what it is supplying. I am using the factory as a dynamic class to provide the app with certain "dependencies" that are needed based on what Java systems are loaded into the server side of the app. Switching between different server side processes in the app will update the app with the dependencies needed to run it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could bind the factory method to itself to avoid the issue, but it's a poor workaround.

As @ste2425 said, you should declare an handler in your controller which will execute the call to the service method and use this handler in your template :

```
<button type="button" ng-click="useHello()">Hello</button>
```

And in your controller :

```
$scope.useHello = function() {
    myFactory.useHello();    
}
```

Also, using prototypal declaration for factories/service, which are singleton by design, is kinda useless.

Comment: I marked this as correct. I do see the problem with what I'm doing in a traditional sense, as you and ste2425 pointed out, but the app I'm writing is far from traditional. Turns out I just made a mistake in where I was declaring the equivalent of useHello in my code which was not properly linking up with the factory. Posted this question too quick I guess. Thanks though!